# def keyword vs rocket ( => ) notation changes function behavior in scala?

Tags: scala, function, lambda

I'm in the process of learning Scala and I am trying to understand the reason behind the first method of defining the function throws an error that "+", "v1" and "v2" are not found while the second method listed below works.

**Method 1:** - using Lambda expressions notation:

```
val addVectLambda = (v1:Vect3,v2:Vect3):Vect3 => (v1._1 + v2._1, v1._2 + v2._2, v1._3 + v2._3)
```

**Method 2:** - using the def keyword:

```
def addVect (v1:Vect3, v2:Vect3):Vect3 = (v1._1 + v2._1, v1._2 + v2._2, v1._3 + v2._3)
```

I apologize if this question has been asked already - I've tried to search but couldn't find an answer. Truly appreciate any help / guidance.

Thanks

**EDIT**: Full code that produces the error message:

```
type Vect3 = (Double, Double, Double)
val addVectLambda = (v1:Vect3,v2:Vect3):Vect3 => (v1._1 + v2._1, v1._2 + v2._2, v1._3 + v2._3)
```

The error message:

```
error: not found: type +
val addVectLambda = (v1:Vect3,v2:Vect3):Vect3 => (v1._1 + v2._1, v1._2 + v2._2, v1._3 + v2._3)
                                                        ^
error: not found: type +
val addVectLambda = (v1:Vect3,v2:Vect3):Vect3 => (v1._1 + v2._1, v1._2 + v2._2, v1._3 + v2._3)
                                                                       ^
error: not found: type +
val addVectLambda = (v1:Vect3,v2:Vect3):Vect3 => (v1._1 + v2._1, v1._2 + v2._2, v1._3 + v2._3)
                                                                                      ^
error: not found: value v1
val addVectLambda = (v1:Vect3,v2:Vect3):Vect3 => (v1._1 + v2._1, v1._2 + v2._2, v1._3 + v2._3)
                     ^
error: not found: value v2
val addVectLambda = (v1:Vect3,v2:Vect3):Vect3 => (v1._1 + v2._1, v1._2 + v2._2, v1._3 + v2._3)
                              ^
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a bizarre error message that you've got there, but it's hardly your fault... I will first give a simple explanation of what's wrong with your first code snippet, and then I will discuss the strange error message that it produces.

---

If you wanted to write down a lambda, you would have to do it like this:

```
type V3 = (Double, Double, Double)
val add = (a: V3, b: V3) => (a._1 + b._1, a._2 + b._2, a._3 + b._3)
```

If you wanted to ascribe the return type explicitly, you would have to add the type ascription on the right hand side:

```
val add2 = (a: V3, b: V3) => ((a._1 + b._1, a._2 + b._2, a._3 + b._3) : V3)
```

another alternative would be to ascribe the type of `add3` explicitly:

```
val add3: (V3, V3) => V3 = 
  (a: V3, b: V3) => (a._1 + b._1, a._2 + b._2, a._3 + b._3)
```

Those are your choices. Just stick to the valid syntax for lambdas, and you should be fine.

---

What follows now is an explanation of why the weird error message makes sense. However, to understand the explanation, one should know at least about type constructors, type members, rules for infix notation, and implicit conversions.

---

If you mistakenly try to append the return type right after the arguments of the lambda:

```
val broken = (a: V3, b: V3): V3 => (a._1 + b._1, a._2 + b._2, a._3 + b._3)
```

you get a bunch of errors

```
error: not found: type +
```

On the first glance, the entire expression seems completely invalid. It is not obvious why this expression should survive the parsing stage of the compilation. However, this is not a compiler bug. We can indeed invent a (fairly contrived) set of definitions such that the above expression becomes valid. Here is one possibility:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
trait +[A, B]
class R
class V3 {
  type _1 = R
  type _2 = R
  type _3 = R
}
val a = new V3
val b = new V3

implicit def conversion(i: (V3, V3)): (V3 => (R + R, R + R, R + R)) = { 
  v: V3 =>
  (new +[R, R]{}, new +[R, R]{}, new +[R, R]{})
}

val notBroken = (a: V3, b: V3): V3 => (a._1 + b._1, a._2 + b._2, a._3 + b._3)

println(notBroken)
```

Here the right hand side of `notBroken` looks essentially the same as the uncompilable (non)-lambda in your question. However, this is perfectly valid `Scala` code, and it even *runs*.

What's going on here:

- `+` is a binary type constructor written in infix notation
- `_1` ... `_3` are type members of the class `V3`, set to `R`
- `a` and `b` are instances of `V3`
- there is a completely insane implicit conversion from `(V3, V3)` to the really ugly function type `V3 => (R + R, R + R, R + R)`
- the `V3 => (a._1 + b._1, ... , ...)` part right from the colon is not a lambda, it's a type ascription
- the type ascription forces the implicit conversion

So, it's valid, though, admittedly, not very helpful in less contrived use cases.