# Scala syntax: why is anonymous function parameter type parsed differently using parenthesis versus curly braces?

Tags: scala, syntax

Given Scala 2.12.6:

```
val list = List(1)
val x = 2
```

This works:

```
list.map ( y => x + y )
```

returning `List[Int] = List(3)`

and this works:

```
list.map ( (y: Int) => x + y )
```

returning the same value.

Same for this:

```
list.map { (y: Int) => x + y }
```

And same for this:

```
list.map { y: Int => x + y }
```

Yet this fails:

```
list.map ( y: Int => x + y )
```

producing the error:

```
error: not found: type +
list.map ( y: Int => x + y )
                       ^
```

Why is Scala thinking the `+` is meant to indicate a type, and where is this difference between using parenthesis and curly braces documented and explained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Section 6.23](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#anonymous-functions) about anonymous functions says:

> In the case of a single untyped formal parameter, (x) => e can be abbreviated to x => e. If an anonymous function (x: T) => e with a single typed parameter appears as the result expression of a block, it can be abbreviated to x: T => e.

Thus, in a block `{ ... }`, the function literal `(y: Int) => x + y` can be abbreviated to just `y: Int => x + y`.

Without the block, the entire `Int => x + y`-part is treated as type ascription, so the error message actually makes sense. For example, here is a context in which the offending expression becomes valid:

```
type y = Unit
type x = Unit
type +[A, B] = Int
val y = (i: Int) => 42 + i

val list = List(1)

println(
  list.map ( y: Int => x + y )
) // happily prints `List(43)`.
```

This is because there are two `y`s in two separate scopes (one value, one type alias), so that `(y: Int => x + y)` becomes `(y: Int => +[x, y])`, and then `(y: Int => Int)`, which is just a type ascription enforcing that value `y` is indeed of function type `Int => Int` (which it is, so everything compiles and runs). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099242/def-keyword-vs-rocket-notation-changes-function-behavior-in-scala/49099528#49099528) is another similar example.

My suggestion: stick to the slightly more verbose `(foo: Foo) => { ... }` notation, it will cause fewer surprises for everyone who tries to read and to modify the code. Otherwise there is some risk that

- argument types in bindings collide with type ascriptions
- `=>` of the anonymous lambda collides with function type `=>`
- arithmetic operation `+` collides with binary infix type constructor `+[_,_]`
- values `x`, `y` collide with undefined types `x`, `y`.

The fact that same syntax can denote both types and expressions can be somewhat of a double-edged sword.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. I'm still unclear on why the error message refers to `+` as the not-found type rather than `x` (or `y`) if it thinks that I'm trying to say that the type of `y` is `Int => x + y`.  In my non-working example there is no type `x` so how did it get past the `x` to the `+`?

Comment: @AdamMackler When the compiler tries to interpret `Int => x + y` as a type, it works with an abstract syntax tree that looks somewhat like `=>[Int, +[x, y]]`, with `=>` at the top, two children `Int` and `+[x, y]`, and then in the right child, a node `+` with leafs `x` and `y`. The compiler scans the AST in top-down fashion, so it encounters `+` first, and then exits with an error message, without getting to `x` and `y`. This is because unlike with values, `+` is not a "method" invoked on `x` (because types have no methods), it's a binary type constructor.